# How does one control the start menu icons

Tags: raspbian, pixel

I have deleted user pi and have another user name in the sudo group for installation. I have locked the root account and don't know the password of my NOOBS image. I have created a 'normal' user.

using the sudo capable user i did the following in a terminal `sudo apt-get install emacs`

the installer has put the emacs icon in 2 places on the start menu that's ok.
The problem is there is no emacs icons on the 'normal' users start menu. Whilst logged on as the 'normal' user i can run emacs.

i thought the question was how do i manually add (and remove) items from the start menu? but it's actually why can't the 'normal' user not see the emacs24.desktop file in /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 0):

Did you login to the normal account when you did it? There’s actually and admin account you can login and install apps on the pi, and you might have done this, and anything done here won’t transfer over to the normal user, you must repeat the install process on the normal user account I

Comment: @sjfklsadfjks after reading your reply I tried creating a new user. All ok on start menu. With a bit of deluser  and adduser I now have a working 'normal' user. Ain't happy it's not a solution it looks like a bug in raspbian or pixel

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo -i` to install it... That always worked for me. If the new user is in every group `pi` was in (except `pi` group), it should work.